# Manjaro MySQL - mariadb.service fails to start

Tags: manjaro, sql, mariadb

When trying to start MariaDB with `systemctl status mariadb`, I get:

```
● mariadb.service - MariaDB 10.3.15 database server
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/mariadb.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since (date)
     Docs: man:mysqld(8)
           https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/systemd/
  Process: 2512 ExecStartPre=/bin/sh -c systemctl unset-environment _WSREP_START_POSITION (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 2513 ExecStartPre=/bin/sh -c [ ! -e /usr/bin/galera_recovery ] && VAR= ||   VAR=`/usr/bin/galera_recovery`; [ $? -eq 0 ]   && systemctl set-environment _WSREP_START_POSITION=$VAR || exit 1 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 2521 ExecStart=/usr/bin/mysqld $MYSQLD_OPTS $_WSREP_NEW_CLUSTER $_WSREP_START_POSITION (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
 Main PID: 2521 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
   Status: "Starting final batch to recover 13 pages from redo log"

[ERROR] Could not open mysql.plugin table. Some plugins may be not loaded
[Note] Recovering after a crash using tc.log
[Note] Starting crash recovery...
[Note] Crash recovery finished.
[ERROR] Can't open and lock privilege tables: Table 'mysql.servers' doesn't exist
[Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
[ERROR] Fatal error: Can't open and lock privilege tables: Table 'mysql.user' doesn't exist
mariadb.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
mariadb.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Failed to start MariaDB 10.3.15 database server.
```

Having followed various tutorials, I may have made it worse. I cannot run `mysql` anymore (in the context of `mysql < file.sql`), since it says `mysql: command not found`.

I have tried removing, reinstalling mariadb and rebooting my computer in between; but I'm out of luck. Any ideas?

**EDIT:** Many others seem to be having this problem,
. Not sure what else I did next as it has been over a year. I do know that following the installation guide [Arch Wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/MariaDB#Installation) page LINE BY LINE will guarantee a proper install. The formatting of the page made me read over things (important things were small, optional things were bold), but make sure you do that right and your installation should work.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I did this solution for me:

```
sudo rm -rf /var/lib/mysql
sudo mysql_install_db --user=mysql --basedir=/usr --datadir=/var/lib/mysql
sudo mysql_secure_installation
```

and then:

```
sudo systemctl restart mariadb
```

Goog luck!